# Is there a way to better write the code to find the number between two numbers? It's not reading the 2nd or the 3rd elif statements

Tags: python

```
BMI_num = 21

if BMI_num <= 18.5:
    BMI_title = 'Underweight'
    print ('Results . . . ')
    print ('Your BMI is: ', BMI_num , '--' , BMI_title) 


elif 18.5 > BMI_num  >= 24.9:
    BMI_title = 'Normal'
    print ('Results . . . ')
    print ('Your BMI is: ', BMI_num , '--' , BMI_title) 


elif 25 >= BMI_num >= 29.9:
    BMI_title = 'Overweight'
    print ('Results . . . ')
    print ('Your BMI is: ', BMI_num , '--' , BMI_title) 


elif BMI_num < 30:
    BMI_title = 'Obese'
    print ('Results . . . ')
    print ('Your BMI is: ', BMI_num , '--' , BMI_title)
```

Comment: Think about the conditions, for what values could they possibly be true?

Comment: I want them to be true for any numbers between 18.5 and 24.9, and 25 and 29.9 but I can't seem to get the write wording for it

Comment: If 18.5 is greater than BMI_num and the BMI_num is greater than or equal to 24.9 won't ever be true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to replace `>` with `<`. Comparisons such as `18.5 > BMI_num  >= 24.9` will always be False as no number can simultaneously be less than 18.5 and more than 24.9.

You also may want to consider that when `BMI_num` is 24.95 or 29.95 no code will be run.

Also you can reduce some code duplication by printing after.

```
if BMI_num <= 18.5:
    BMI_title = 'Underweight'
elif 18.5 < BMI_num  < 25:
    BMI_title = 'Normal'
elif 25 <= BMI_num <= 29.9:
    BMI_title = 'Overweight'
elif BMI_num < 30:
    BMI_title = 'Obese'

print ('Results . . . ')
print (f'Your BMI is: {BMI_num} -- {BMI_title}')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your method is actually to see if a number is between two numbers completely fine. It is just that your range is wrong.
For the second if statement, 18.5 > BMI_num >= 24.9 is never possible. 24.9 is not less than 18.5. I believe you meant

```
    elif 18.5 < BMI_num <= 24.9:
        # some code that runs because this elif is true.
```

For the third elif, 29.9 can't be less than or equal to 25. You should change it too

```
    elif 25 <= BMI_num <= 29.9:
        # some code that runs because this elif is true
```

The fourth and first if statements are fine.

You might want to change your fourth if statement to

```
    elif BMI_num >= 29.9
        # some code that runs because this elif is true
```

because the only way it would work with the previous statements is if BMI_num is > 29.9 and less than 30. It also includes 29.9 to 30, unlike doing

```
    elif BMI_num >= 30
        # some code that runs because this elif is true
```

It could also be

```
    else:
        """
        some code that runs because all the previous ones were 
        false
        """
```

Another method is

```
    if {variable_name} in range(x, y)
```

, but don't use the curly braces, but just the variable, which in this code is BMI_num, and x, y are the two numbers. The range is all numbers from x to y excluding y. Add/subtract one from either variable to get the right range

Comment: `if BMI_num in range(start, stop)` only works if `BMI_num` is an integer

Answer (score 0):

The comparator signs in the `elif` conditionals are wrong, as they are the wrong direction and also do not cover the boundary cases. I would also suggest to use a function and also drop the redundant print statements, as follows:

```
def log_bmi(BMI_num):
    if BMI_num <= 18.5:
        BMI_title = 'Underweight'
    elif 18.5 < BMI_num <= 25:
        BMI_title = 'Normal'
    elif 25 < BMI_num <= 30:
        BMI_title = 'Overweight'
    else:
        BMI_title = 'Obese'
    print ('Results . . . ')
    print ('Your BMI is: ', BMI_num , '--' , BMI_title)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def log_bmi(BMI_num):
    if BMI_num <= 18.5:
        BMI_title = 'Underweight'
    elif BMI_num <= 25:
        BMI_title = 'Normal'
    elif BMI_num <= 30:
        BMI_title = 'Overweight'
    else:
        BMI_title = 'Obese'
    print ('Results . . . ')
    print ('Your BMI is: ', BMI_num , '--' , BMI_title)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
labels = {0.1: "Underweight",  18.5: "Normal", 24.9: "Overweight", 29.9: "Obese"}
ibm = 21
print([labels[label] for label in labels if ibm/label >= 1][-1])
```

a simple, 2lines way and just for fun (because it's readability is low)